# Resolution Proof Question

Tags: logic

> Given the implication $[(p\vee (q\wedge r) \wedge (p\to s)] \to (r\vee s)$, establish the validity of the argument using resolution.

This is the answer my textbook gave:

> $$\begin{array}{rll}1&p\vee(q\wedge r)&\textrm{Premise}\\
> 2&(p\vee q)\wedge(p\vee r)&\textrm{Step 1 and Distributive Law}\\
> 3&p\vee r&\textrm{Step 2 Rule of Conjunctive Simplification}\\
> 4&p\to s&\textrm{Premise}\\
> 5&!p\vee s&\textrm{Step 4, }p\to s\Leftrightarrow\,!p\vee s\\
> 6&r\vee s&\textrm{Steps 3 and 5, Rule of the Conjunction and Resolution}\end{array}$$

Why is $p\vee q$ not used in step 6, with the resolvent as $r\vee s\vee q$?

Comment: I don't understand your question. Why would you want to get $R\vee s\vee q$, when you are asked to get $r\vee s$?

Answer (score 1):

What is called in Step 6 : Rule of the Conjunction and Resolution, is called also Resolution (see Wiki : [List of rules of inference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_rules_of_inference):

> from $p \lor r$ and $\lnot p \lor s$, $\quad r \lor s$ follows.

So in your proof, in Step 5 you use the

> equivalence between $p \rightarrow s$ and $\lnot p \lor s$,

and in Step 6 you must use *Resolution* to get , from $p \lor r$ (Step 3) and $\lnot p \lor s$ (Step 5) to :

> > $r \lor s$.

Answer (score 0):

The clauses $p \vee r$ (from step 3) and $\neg p \vee s$ (from step 5) together imply $r \vee s$, which gives you what you need. $q$ was not really needed.